# Recursive Descent Parser LL(4) with example

Tags: java, parsing, recursive-descent

I want to define a grammar that the language generated from the grammar needs LL(4) recursive descent parser. The grammar doesn't need to be complicated, as long as it satisfies the requirement?

the if statement for the grammar can be as follows

```
if lookahead ∈ FIRST(Something) then
code for Something ...
else if lookahead ∉ FOLLOW(Something
?
) then
ERROR;
Something
*
can be implemented as a while loop:
while lookahead ∈ FIRST(Something) do
code for Something ...
if lookahead ∉ FOLLOW(Something
*
) then
ERROR;
and Something
+
can be implemented as a repeat loop:
repeat
if lookahead ∉ FIRST(Something) then
ERROR;
code for Something ...
until lookahead ∈ FOLLOW(Something
+
);
```

Comment: Consider including a question in your post.

Comment: @MintyFresh I know how to write the parser implementation. But I am looking for an example grammar (any syntax) where the parser is required to used exactly 4 look ahead tokens to make the parsing decisions

Comment: Really consider clarifying what you have done, what you have encountered and what you are asking.

Comment: @MSB I guess you did not get what i am asking for. Its ok, but you can clarify before marking it down.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite degenerate example grammar (easily parsed with an LR(1) parser, btw):

```
s: a | b | ID;
a: "x" "x" "x" "(" s "," s ")"
b: "x" "x" "x" "[" s "]"
```

Comment: Well, this is an LL(4) grammar, but an LL(1) grammar exists that describes the same language: `s: "x" "x" "x" c | ID; c: a | b; a: "(" s "," s ")"; b: "[" s "]";`

Comment: @Gunther: True. But the OP didn't ask for an LL(4) language, just an LL(4) grammar. (By the way, all LR(k) languages which are not LR(0) are LR(1); also true of LALR. But that doesn't always help much when you're writing a parser.)

Answer (score 1):

[Parsing Techniques](http://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_2nd_Edition/) by Grune and Jacobs (also available [online](http://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_1st_Edition/BookBody.pdf)) on page 181 shows this example of an LL(k+1) *language* that is not LL(k):

```
S ::= a S A 
    | 
A ::= aᵏ b S 
    | c
```

Accordingly this grammar describes an LL(4) *language*:

```
S ::= a S A 
    | 
A ::= a a a b S 
    | c
```

The grammar is in fact strong-LL(4), and LALR(4), but neither LL(3), nor LR(3).

For an LL(4) *grammar*, this one will do:

```
S ::= a a a 
    | A a a a a
A ::=
```

Also strong-LL(4), and LALR(4), but neither LL(3), nor LR(3).